# Will be dispose called on dependency injection object?

Tags: idisposable

I am concerning, if `GC` will call dispose method on `IDisposable` argument passing to object creating in `using() {}` statement.

```
HttpClient
```

and

```
HTTPHttpClientHandler
```

are `IDisposable` classes.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
}//1
```

//1 In this point GC will call `dispose()` method on client.
**Does it mean**, that `dispose()` method will be called on `handler` too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If you view the code for the `HttpClient.Dispose()`, it calls `base.Dispose()` which does the following:

`this.handler.Dispose();` where `handler` is an instance of `HttpMessageHandler` and `HttpClientHandler : HttpMessageHandler`.

Also, if you ran the code you have written as is, once the using block has completed, you will see that the `handler.disposed` is set to true (using the debugger in Visual Studio).